# C# satisfy members of two interfaces with one property

Tags: c#

Issue origin: I have a generic component to display data. The data may come from different data models. To unify the access inside the component I created one interface `IOne` that gets implemented by all classes. In order to abstract the data access layer from the application I'm using interfaces for each data model. So each data display model implements the `IOne` interface and additionally one of the data model interfaces.
The interfaces:

```
public interface IOne
{
    public int idNameOne { get; set; }
}

public interface DataModelOne
{
    public int anotherNameForId{ get; set; }
}
```

In my class I want both members to be satisfied by one single property. My current solution is as follows:

```
public class Implementation : IOne, DataModelOne
{
    private int _id; 
    public idNameOne { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public anotherIdName { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
}
```

Is there any way to declare that one property satisfies both members? What would be a clean solution for this?

Comment: You could make one an auto property, it would clean up the code a little.

Comment: Why do your DataModel classes need individual names for their id in the first place? Having different names does feel suboptimal even when there was some kind of alias feature in the language.

Comment: @Ralf I agree. I'm receiving the data from a db where it is defined like that. So I have to work with it...

Comment: So you say that your model mapper is incapable of mapping the presumably primary key in your db to a freely choosen name like Id? Your classes look handmade. So i assume your model mapper is also handmade. Why not just fixing the model mapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no other way than what you are doing. I'd however clean up the code (and do proper casing), by removing the backing field (and use one auto-property) and only have the other one reference the first... something like:

```
public class Implementation : IOne, IDataModelOne
{
    public int IdNameOne { get; set }
    public int AnotherIdName { get => IdNameOne; set => IdNameOne = value; }
}
```

(notice I've used the proper casing for the properties... should be the same casing on the interfaces too... also named `IDataModelOne` correctly, with an `I` prefix)

Comment: @MindSwipe was editing just that when your edit popped up, nice catch, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having both on the public API, you should usually use "explicit interface implementation" for this, for example:

```cs
public class Implementation : IOne, DataModelOne
{
    public int idNameOne { get; set; }
    int DataModelOne.anotherNameForId
    {
        get => idNameOne;
        set => idNameOne = value;
    }
}
```

or

```cs
public class Implementation : IOne, DataModelOne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    int IOne.idNameOne
    {
        get => Id;
        set => Id = value;
    }
    int DataModelOne.anotherNameForId
    {
        get => Id;
        set => Id = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I really had to do this I would make the `idNameOne` property an auto property with `anotherIdName`'s getter and setter referring to that property.

```
public class Implementation : IOne, DataModelOne
{
    public idNameOne { get; set; }
    public anotherIdName { get { return idNameOne; } set { idNameOne = value; } }
}
```

It's a little bit cleaner and show the intention a little better too.